# Url Routing Question multiple departments

Tags: asp.net

I want my url to look like this www.website.com/browse/computers/consoles/playstation-3/en-NZ.aspx. The part where it starts - browse which I guess is my controller - computers/consoles/playstation-3 is my action and - en-NZ.aspx is the page I want to name it. My three questions are how do you set up the action part when there are multiple departments and what is the regular expression for en-NZ for the CultureInfo is it `/\{2, [a-z]}\-\{2, [A-Z]}` I also need that expression to have it for two lower case letters for turkey e.g **tr** wich is the only language code with two letters. And how do you access a particluar department in the url after the {browse}/{*multipleDepartments}/ part.

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    "browse",  //Name of the Route (can be anyuthting)
    "{*departments}/regexp goes here.aspx", // parameters not to sure about the* 
    "~/Departments.aspx"); //Page which will handles and process the request
}
```

check my comments
Also I have created a CTE Expression which createds the Url for me it builds a link like the example above /computers/consoles/playstation-3 if I have to put that in parameters how Do i deal with that in a parameters url, what I mean is the parameters would be multiple on the same query like Departments.aspx?a=computersb=consoles&c=playstation-3. I wouldn't know how deep the query is so what do I do if it's in this case dealing with parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way... the culture info shouldn't be the page name, it should be part of the url. You don't normally create separate pages for different languages, instead you use resources to localise a page.

With URL routing, generally the make-up of a route follows the pattern `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

So the URL you are looking to route would look similar to this:

```
www.website.com/en-NZ/consoles/list/playstation-3
```

For further reference, check out these good tutorials:

- Scott Guthrie: [ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 2): URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)
- Stephen Walther: [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: +1 My thoughts exactly. Culture info is definitely not the page name. I'd go even further and say that if this is used for l10n, it should be a parameter and not part of the URL at all.