# Regular Expression for CultureInfo

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex

What is the regular expression for en-NZ for the CultureInfo, is it /{2, [a-z]}-{2, [A-Z]} ?

I also need for the expression to check for Turkey, which is two lower case letters. For example 'tr' which is the only language code with two letters.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're saying.  What is the regular expression supposed to match?  How is 'tr' the only language code with two letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\b[a-z]{2,3}(?:-[A-Z]{2,3}(?:-(?:Cyrl|Latn))?)?\b/
```

Explanation:

```
\b               # word boundary
[a-z]{2,3}       # 2-3 lowercase letters
(?:              # Try to match the following:
 -[A-Z]{2,3}     #  dash, 2-3 uppercase letters
 (?:             #  Try to match...
  -              #   dash
  (?:Cyrl|Latn)  #   Cyrl or Latn
 )?              #  optionally
)?               # optionally
\b               # word boundary
```

This matches all of these valid CultureInfo codes:

```
tr
tr-TR
syr
sr-SP-Latn
kok-IN
zh-CHT
```

Comment: thankyou that helps can you this question I posted earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644540/url-routing-question-multiple-departments you sound like you know your stuff

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what your asking so here is a very good regex generation site.

http://www.txt2re.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is a regex that finds two lowercase letters, followed by a dash, followed by two uppercase letters, then use:

```
[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work.

```
/([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}|[a-z]{2})/
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal regex syntax would be

```
[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}
```

but the problem with this is that it will also match *en-AU* (ugh, the horrors of it...), *en-GB*, *en-US*, *fr-FR*, etc.

What you can use instead to search for that specific value is this:

```
var re = /en-NZ/;
```

[Here is the W3C tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) on Javascript regexes, and [this page](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) also has a javascript regex tester (select the *Client-side Engine* in the top dropdown, and the *JavaScript* engine in the dropdown at the bottom of the page).